# Get IP ADDRESS from MAC ADDRESS for Printers

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get IP from MAC Address of printer.
I have got MAC address and want to know what IP is assigned to it via DHCP server.

I tried the below query and it does give me all the IP address in scope but I need to be able to search for the one I am looking for.

```
netsh dhcp server \\DHCP server scope 10.65.22.0 show clients 1
```

I tried using `Where {$_.uniqueID -like "002128903a09"}` but it does not seems to like it.

Thanks

Comment: If you can upgrade to PowerShell v.4 and have Server 2012 as your DHCP server, you can now use a bunch of cmdlets to get DHCP data.   [DHCP Server Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590751%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `netsh` is an external application, and will return a bunch of text, but not objects, so you can't check a property (like `$_.uniqueID`) using a `Where` statement. You have two options here, you can search for the line of text that has your MAC and consume the whole line, or you can parse the text and convert it to objects. I am not familiar with the results that get spit out when you run that command, so if you want to give a sample of that (update your question to include it, don't put it in a comment), I can probably help you parse the text into objects, or just search it for a MAC address.

Or, one option would be to pipe the command into the `Select-String` cmdlet, and have that search for your MAC address.

```
$MACAddr = ("002128903a09" -split "(..)"|?{$_}) -join "-"
netsh dhcp server \\DHCP server scope 10.65.22.0 show clients 1 | Select-String -SimpleMatch $MACAddr
```

I believe that will at least find the line that has your MAC, and you can get the IP from there.

**Edit:** Updated with MAC Address formatting corrected, thanks to @JanChrbolka for helping me with the correct format!

Comment: DHCP server stores and returns MAC addresses in different format "00-21-28-90-3a-09".  Here is a really ugly way of converting the MAC so you can do a string search. `$DHCPmac = $mac.Substring(0,2) + '-' + $mac.Substring(2,2) + '-' + $mac.Substring(4,2) + '-' + $mac.Substring(6,2) + '-' + $mac.Substring(8,2) + '-' + $mac.Substring(10,2)`

Comment: @JanChrbolka Thanks! Plus, there's an easier way using `-Split` and `-Join`. Try this: `$DHCPmac = ($mac -split "(..)"|Where{$_}) -join "-"` ...that will split the string on every 2 characters, pass an array, filtering out blank entries, to the `Join` that joins the array with dashes. Comes out just like yours, but is a lot shorter.